# C# saving to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have the following converted into a dynamic object. Here is what the object looks like:

```
"rejectionReason": null,
"timestamp": {
  "testDate1": null,
  "testDate2": null,
  "testDate3": null,
  "testDate4": null,
  "testDate5": "2016-03-23T15:41:22.000-06:00",
  "testDate6": "2016-03-23T15:36:32.000-06:00",
  "testDate7": "2016-03-23T15:39:22.000-06:00"
},
"outsideTestDate": null,
```

I can save to the `outsideTestDate` easily by using:

```
dynamicObj.outsideTestDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

However I'm trying to save to `testDate1` - `testDate4` but can't seem to get it to work and comes back null everytime and seems to be with the left-hand side of the expression. I have tried:

```
dynamicObj.timestamp.testDate4 = DateTimeOffset.Now
```

any ideas that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you converting json to c# object or the other way round ?

Comment: How do you convert to `dynamic`? And how do you check for `null`? I'm using `Json.NET` and this works fine for me: `dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json); data.timestamp.testDate4 = DateTimeOffset.Now;`

Comment: I guess I should have clarified, I am pulling from a azure document db so I am converting json to C#

Answer (score 0):

Not a very pretty solution but here is what I did to get it to work

```
DateTimeOffset td5 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(inspection.timestamp.testDate5.ToString());
DateTimeOffset td6 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(inspection.timestamp.testDate6.ToString());
DateTimeOffset td7 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(inspection.timestamp.testDate7.ToString());

        dynamicObj.timestamp = new
                    {
                        testDate1 = (DateTimeOffset?)null,
                        testDate2 = (DateTimeOffset?)null,
                        testDate3 = (DateTimeOffset?)null,
                        testDate4 = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        testDate5 = td5,
                        testDate6 = td6,
                        testDate7 = td7
                    };
```